# How does the following foward-declared multi-inheritance pointer converted code work?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, forward-declaration

In the followint code, how does the pointer conversion & multi-inheritance play together?

```
class Foo {
  public:
  virtual void someFunc();
};

class Bar;


void someWork(Bar *bar) {
  ((Foo*) bar)->someFunc();
}

class Bar: public Zed, public Foo {
...
virtual void someFunc() { ... do something else ... }
}

Bar bar;

int main() {
  someWork(&bar);
}
```

My understanding is kinda shaky.

On one hand, someWork knows nothing about Bar, so this shouldn't work; but on the other hand, I have forward declared Bar.

Thanks!

Comment: This answer to another question has a good list of what you can and cannot do with an incomplete type:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration/553869#553869

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work and it isn't doing quite what you think it is.  Your use of the c-style cast:

```
(Foo*) bar
```

is incorrect in this case.  What you are trying to do is upcast the `Bar*` to a `Foo*` (i.e., perform a `static_cast` from a pointer to a dervied class to a pointer to a base class).

Since the definition of `Bar` is not available at this point, however, the compiler does not know that `Foo` is a base class of `Bar`.  Thus, the `static_cast` fails and the compiler falls back and uses a `reinterpret_cast`, which is not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. My guess is that since the cast is "evaluated" during linking, which is after the class has been compiled. But that's just a guess.